# Rest : How to identify an action non resource related

Tags: rest, url-design

I would like to use the Rest-Easy framework to develop my application. 
My application is VOIP (telephony) related.
It can :

- Originate a phone call between two phone numbers
- Transfer a phone call
- Perform CRUD actions on resources

Those phone calls are not saved and thus are not considered as resources in my application.

How should I name the rest url to originate a phone call ?

- /originate/numberA,numberB
- /originate/[numberA,numberB]
- /number/numberA/originate/numberB
- other?

Same goes for transfer (where 3 parameters (phone numbers) are required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST has *nothing* to do with the URL design and there's no such thing as *"REST URL"*.

---

However, once REST is *resource*-oriented, I strong advise you to pick a URL that describes your resource (a *call* in your situation).

I would recommend the following (sending the parameters in the request payload):

```json
POST /calls HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "from": "number goes here",
  "to": "number goes here"
}
```

Comment: Should I have used the term restful api? Thanks for the quick and complete reply

Comment: @Gabriel If you API follow the constraints defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Fielding's dissertation, then _yes_, you have a _RESTful API_. Otherwise it's a _Web API_.